# How to execute javascript code after appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

I'm having a problem when I use `appendChild()` to append a `<script>` tag where the javascript referenced in the new script tag is not run. In Firebug I get a notification which says "Reload the page to get source" but if I reload the JS will be appendChild again.

Here is my code:

```
var divAd = document.createElement("div");
divAd.innerHTML = '<script src="http:example.com/adenseload.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>';
titleBak.appendChild(divAd);
```

How can I use the appended JS after using appendChild()?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: are you sure that the src-property is correct and the loaded js-file actually calls a method after being loaded?

Comment: yes the src is corrent.i'm appendChild() when load document in another js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't wrap it in a div, create the script tag directly. This worked for me:

```
var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
scriptTag.src = "http://example.com/myscript.js";
bodyTag.appendChild(scriptTag);
```

Comment: i think you code is true but divAd.innerHTML = ajaxResult in my case is result from ajax so i cant create element script because already in result.

Comment: You could deliver only the url via ajax instead of the whole script-tag.

Comment: you true, why i'm not hink like that...stupid... i'm using code thi for get src from javascript tag `var adScript = ad.getElementsByTagName("script");
        var index = adScript.length - 1;
        var adsScr = adScript[index]; var src = adsSrc.src;`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use below statement to load JS,
`document.write('<script src="', 'http:example.com/adenseload.js', '" type="text/JavaScript"><\/script>');`. 
 
 you can append HTMLobjects only to the DIV, Not script tags